# How can I recover my ext4 ubuntu partition from my windows parition?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, ext4

I dual boot windows and ubuntu 10.04. I accidentally did an `rm -r *` in my `home` directory and deleted a bunch of files and folders that I need to recover. How can I recover these files from my  windows xp partition? If there's isn't a way to do this from windows, what's the best way to do it in ubuntu? I'd prefer a graphical interface if that's possible. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you can avoid booting into Ubuntu, do it.  Ubuntu will start using diskspace marked now as "free" for newly created files (writing over your deleted files), so if you can do it from windows, or a live boot disk of Ubuntu, you have a better chance of restoring all your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu you're pretty much screwed if you do a command line rm -r *.  Had you done it via gnome graphical interface you could just restore from trash.  If what you're saying is that you mounted an NTFS filesystem with Ubuntu and did the rm inside that directory, then you might have a chance.  This URL might apply... https://superuser.com/questions/6810/best-undelete-tool-for-ntfs-fat

NOTE THE CAVEAT - you must not have used programs that write to the disk where the deleted files live.

GOOD LUCK - and make backups next time :-)

Hotei

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of Recovery Tools from [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd).